# How to turn words into numbers with a comma between each number in Python

Tags: python

Hi~I'm new to python and I got a practice like this, which I have tried several ways but still can't get the exact output:

I want to write a program that turns words into numbers, in which:

> a=1 b=2 c=3 .... and z=26,

and a comma separates each number

For example:

> When input = apple, the desired output = 1,16,16,12,5
>
> When input = mac, the desired output = 13,1,3

Below are my failed codings:

```
word=input()
lst=[]
for n in word:
    i = str(ord(n)-96)
    lst += i
print(",".join(lst))
```

The first one above separated every digits in which the output for "mac" becomes "1,3,1,3"

```
word=input()
for n in word:
    print((ord(n)-96), end= ",")
```

The second one adds "," after every digit, like "13,1,3,", but I don't want a comma at the end of the output.

Could anyone give me some advice, please? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word=input()
lst=[]
for n in word:
    i = str(ord(n)-96)
    lst.append(i)
print(",".join(lst))
```